# How do I restore firefox addon that has been removed from toolabar?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

I accidentally clicked on remove from toolbar option for one of my firefox add-on. The add-on is still installed, but not visible on the toolbar.

I couldn't find any settings that would allow me to make the add-on show up on my toolbar again. And the problem is persisting even after reinstalling the add-on.

Answer (score 1):

Click on the 3-line at the top right, then Customize. Your extension's button should be among the button shown. Find it, then drag it to the toolbar.